# Linux Container LXC Intra Host Networking Issues

Tags: networking, bridge, lxc, container

I have a problem that I cannot seem to resolve. I have two hosts M and N. A container in host M can ping the gateway, its host and all containers in Host N but cannot ping any co-hosted container in host M. The same with containers in host N that can ping all containers in host M but cannot ping any of its co-hosted containers. I have verified that they all have unique hardware address.

My hosts run on ubuntu 14.04 but all containers run on ubuntu 12.04. I had to use 12.04 to accommodate Ambari from Horton Works that does not yet support 14.04.

Network - > Bridge br0 (I have 2 Network adapters)

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

## First Adapter

auto p130p1

iface p130p1 inet static

address 192.168.1.9
netmask 255.255.255.0

network 192.168.1.0

broadcast 192.168.1.255

gateway 192.168.1.1

dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

## Second Adapter Bridge

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0

iface br0 inet dhcp

bridge_ports eth0

bridge_stp off

bridge_fd 0

bridge_maxwait 0